# Why does the form view of a grid jump to the first record

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom Form/Detail screen that uses the standard Acumatica architecture, i.e., linked by key fields in the header and grid along with a LastLineNumber field in the header and a LineNbr field in the grid.  This all works fine,  just the way it should.

The problem is - I've added the ability to edit the grid row in a form view, which works as expected, except that when I sort the records by any given field in the grid view, either asc or desc, when I go to the form view it opens the first record in the grid regardless of which record I was on in the grid.  When I remove the sort, it doesn't jump to the first record  any longer.

Any idea what's happening, or how I can get this to stop happening?  Anyone seen this before?

FYI - this is build 20.102.0015..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have `SyncPosition="True"` property on `PXGrid` control?

Can you reproduce the issue in Sales Order screen Details tabs?

Comment: Yeah - that was it.  Sorry - I should've thought of that.  That's one of those properties where I think, why wouldn't that be the default behavior?  Why would you NOT want the position to by synced?   Thanks much, Hugues... ;D

Comment: It's because of performance optimization. To troubleshoot this type of issue, find a similar feature in the base product (like Sales Order Details grid) and compare the ASPX control (FormView) properties.